# how can i create Spark DataFrame From .Thrift file's struct Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, thrift

I tried this

```
val temp = Seq[ProcessAction]()  // ProcessAction is declared in Thrift
val toDF = temp.toDF()
```

I got the error

> scala.ScalaReflectionException: none is a term

if I use case class object rather than `ProcessAction` I can get the DataFrame...

Are there any ways to get rid of this error??

Answer (score 0):

Parquet files understand Thrift encoded objects so you could use ThriftParquetWriter to load a parquet file and then use Spark SQL or something to get those objects into a DataFrame.

https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-thrift/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/thrift/ThriftParquetWriter.java